# Multiple conditions in one SQL query for update

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing a problem in MySql query. I want to update a database field by 0 where ID= 100 and the rest of field will change by 1. Is it possible for one SQL? I tried it in many ways. It's not working.

```
$query="UPDATE test set cl3='0' where Id='100' AND set cl3='1' where Id!='100'";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a `case`:

```
update test
    set cl3 = (case when id = 100 then 0 else 1 end);
```

Or, even more simply:

```
update test
    set cl3 = (id <> 100);  -- slightly different result if `id` can be `NULL`
```